# escape new line charater in column fields while reading data imported using sqoop

Tags: hadoop, hbase, sqoop

I am importing data from sql table to hdfs and storing as file. on column is xml and has new line character. so while reading this data, it is getting split incorrectly. is dere a way to improvise in sqoop or while reading ?

Comment: Can you please post your Sqoop command and datatype for xml column?

Comment: import
-D
hbase.client.keyvalue.maxsize=0
 --connect
<connection details>
 --username
  <username>
  --password-file
  <path>
--driver
  <driver>
--query
 <query>
  -m
         1
--fields-terminated-by 
|
--target-dir
<targetfolder>

variable type in sql for xml is nvarchar

Comment: Can you try with passing argument `--map-column-java your_xml_column=String` in Sqoop command.